# Distributed k-means in Spark

Tags: clustering, k-means, apache-spark, distributed, scala

I want to implement K-means algorithm in Spark. I am looking for a starting point and I found [Berkeley's naive implementation](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rxin/ampcamp-ecnu/machine-learning-with-spark.html). However, is that distributed?

I mean I see no mapreduce operations. Or maybe, when submitted in Spark, the framework actually makes the needed tricks under the hood to distribute the algorithm?

<sub>I also found that [Spark shows mapreduce the exit](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2982475/big-data/spark-15-shows-mapreduce-the-exit.html) and I am using Spark 1.6.</sub>

---

EDIT: This code produces a runtime error, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35373478/mapping-of-elements-gone-bad).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In that link you posted, you can look at the python full solution [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rxin/ampcamp-ecnu/machine-learning-with-spark.html#solution_11) at the end and go through it to see what all is distributed. 
In short, some parts are distributed, like reading data from the file, but the very important parts like the distance computation are not.

Running down, we see:

> `sc = SparkContext("local[6]", "PythonKMeans")`

This instantiates the context and creates a local cluster which the jobs will be submitted to

> `lines = sc.textFile(..)`

This is still setting up. No operations have taken place yet. You can verify this by putting timing statements in the code

> `data = lines.map(lambda x: (x.split("#")[0], parseVector(x.split("#")[1])))`

The lambda here will be applied to lines, so this operation will split the file in parallel. Note that the actual line also has a `cache()` at the end (see [cache](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#caching)]). `data` is just a reference to the spark object in memory. (I may be wrong here, but I think the operation still doesn't happen yet)

> count = data.count()

This forces the parallel computation to start, and the count to be stored. At the end, the reference data is still valid, and we'll use it for further computations. I'll stop with detailed explanations here, but wherever `data` is being used is a possible parallel computation. The python code itself is single threaded, and interfaces with the Spark cluster.

An interesting line is:

> tempDist = sum(np.sum((centroids[x] - y) ** 2) for (x, y) in newCentroids.iteritems())

`centroids` is an object in python memory, as is `newCentroids`. So, at this point, all computations are being done in memory (and **on the client**, typically clients are slim, i.e. have limited capabilities, or the client is an SSH shell, so the computers resources are shared. You should ideally *never* do any computation here), so no parallelization is being used. You could optimize this method further by doing this computation in parallel. Ideally you want the python program to never directly handle individual points' $x$ and $y$ values.

Comment: Great explanation, @Harsh!

Comment: Tnx! So: We have our initial dataset, which is distributed (every node takes a subset of the dataset S). Then, every node computes distances (serially) and finds the new centroids for their respective S. Then what is happening? Every node continues running its local kmeans in its subset of the dataset or we split again the dataset to the nodes, but now we use the centroids computed in the previous iteration?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about that specific implementation, but we use the [mllib k-means](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-clustering.html) here at my work, to some degree of success. It is distributed and runs on Spark!

Comment: Kyle yes I have seen that, but in my question I said: "*I want to implement K-means algorithm in Spark*".

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I misread!

Comment: It's OK Kyle, it's good info, thus my +1. I may explore the source code of mllib and compare it with the one I linked! I also updated my question, if that matters.

Comment: No problem! That's a great place to start!

Comment: And a big one too. I found this, looking into it now...https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering